# button function with ternary operator

Tags: jquery

I  have the following code that is applied to a forward and next button. I also have the submit button that starts the process. It is desired that after you hit submit button (#lookup) it shows the forward and next to paginate through the results. The problem is that after the initial submit/#lookup and you hit forward and submit another search it shows the results from the second set/where you were on the first search after hitting next (IE starts at results 51-100 instead of back at 1). I need to modify the following

```
function changestart(direction) 
{
var rowsElement  = $("#maxrows");
var rowsValue    = parseInt(rowsElement.val());
var startElement = $("#startID");
var value        = parseInt(startElement.val());
startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ? value -
rowsValue : 1);
}
$("#previous").click(function(){changestart('back');});
$("#next").click(function(){changestart('forward');});
// not working
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart('???');});
```

EDIT - the button currently has this inline JS

```
<input id="lookup" type="submit" name="lookup" value="Search" onclick="changestart('1')" />
```

How do I apply a click function to the submit button "#lookup" that starts the search back at 1?
thx

Comment: can you add html hint; $("#maxrows").text() or $("#maxrows").val() if you are not getting correct value

Comment: I basically want to remove the inline JS and add it as a click function where it says // not working please see edit, sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a lot of ways, but why not treat direction as a optional argument, which when not set indicates a reset condition.

```
function changestart(direction) 
{
  var startElement = $("#startID");
  if ( direction ) {
    var rowsElement  = $("#maxrows");
    var rowsValue    = parseInt(rowsElement.val());
    var value        = parseInt(startElement.val());
    startElement.val(direction == "forward" ? value + rowsValue : direction == "back" ? value -
rowsValue : 1);
  } else {
    startElement.val( 0 );
  }
}
$("#previous").click(function(){changestart('back');});
$("#next").click(function(){changestart('forward');});
// not working
$("#lookup").click(function(){changestart();});
```

Comment: thanks man, i was unaware you didn't have to use .val(1), then learned its just ...{changestart(1)... and see that since it defaults to 1 you don't even need that. Thanks!